# Undefined references when compiling a static Qt build on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mingw32

I'd like to compile a static version of the Qt toolkit on the Windows platform (Windows XP SP3). I downloaded the latest release for Windows and successfully installed it. Then I opened the Qt 4.6.3 Command Prompt from the Start menu and invoked:

`configure -static -release -nomake examples -nomake demos -fast`

Configuration executes fine, and the first part of `mingw32-make` as well. At some point I get a lot of undefined references:

> mingw32-make[4]: Entering directory `C:/Qt-static/4.6.3/src/tools/moc'
>   g++ -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT
>   -DQT_MOC -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_LITE_UNICODE -DQT_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_AS
>   CII -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CODECS -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT
>    -DQT_NO_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_SYSTEMLOCALE -DQT_NO_TEXTST
>   REAM -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_NODLL -I"
>   ." -I"." -I"......\include" -I"......\include\QtCore" -I"......\include\Qt
>   Xml" -I"....\xml" -I"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\SDK\v1.
>   1\include" -I"......\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o release\moc.o moc.cpp
>
> ...
>
> g++ -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-rel
>   oc -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -Wl -o ......\bin\moc.exe release/m
>   oc.o release/preprocessor.o release/generator.o release/parser.o release/token.o
>    release/main.o  -L"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\SDK\v1.1\
>   Lib\" -LC:/Qt-static/4.6.3/src/tools/bootstrap/release -lbootstrap -luser32
>   release/moc.o:moc.cpp:(.text+0x14b): undefined reference to `QByteArray::shared_
>   null'
>
>   release/moc.o:moc.cpp:(.text+0x150): undefined reference to`QByteArray::shared_
>   null'
>   release/moc.o:moc.cpp:(.text+0x156): undefined reference to `QByteArray::shared_
>
> ...

The list of undefined references is actually much longer.

This is out of the box on a pretty default Windows installation. I wonder whether I'm doing something wrong or there's a bug in the toolkit.

Comment: Have you seen where QByteArry::shared_null is defined? It is vastly more likely that you've mis-configured the installation then a such a broadly used package is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems. In my case Visual Studio had set environment parameters
`INCLUDE` and `LIB` which confused the make.

The solution was to disable them from the command line

```
set INCLUDE=
set LIB=
```

before compiling the Qt libraries.

Comment: Yeah, this is a good candidate for causing the problem: the -I".NET 2003..." flag also got me thinking that there was a mixup of mingw and msvc libraries/headers.